# Fabric JS : I need to delete an quadratic curved arrow tool after once created on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to make a quadratic curved arrow tool.

I was used demo in the following link for creating the tool.
http://kpomservices.com/oldweb/HTML5_Canvas_Curved_Lines.php

i was success to create an tool as I needs.
but I am getting some issues with that.
Hope someone here can help me on that issues...
here is the code I am using for creating the tool ..

```
        line_number++;
        var line;
        var reinit_stroke = "";

        fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';
        function _getQBezierValue(t, p1, p2, p3) {
            var iT = 1 - t;
            return iT * iT * p1 + 2 * iT * t * p2 + t * t * p3;
        }

        function getQuadraticCurvePoint(startX, startY, cpX, cpY, endX, endY, position) {
            return {
                x: _getQBezierValue(position, startX, cpX, endX),
                y: _getQBezierValue(position, startY, cpY, endY)
            };
        }
        canvas.on({
            'object:selected': onObjectSelected,
            'object:moving': onObjectMoving,
            'before:selection:cleared': onBeforeSelectionCleared
        });

        (function drawQuadratic() {

            line = new fabric.Path('M 65 0 Q 100, 100, 200, 0', { fill: '', selectable: false,hasBorders: false,hasControls: false,stroke: #000});

            line.path[0][1] = posx;
            line.path[0][2] = posy;

            line.path[1][1] = posx+50;
            line.path[1][2] = posy+50;

            line.path[1][3] = posx+100;
            line.path[1][4] = posy+100;


            line.id = line_number;

            //line.selectable = false;
            canvas.add(line);

            canvas.sendBackwards(line);

            var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(line.path[0][1], line.path[0][2], line.path[1][1], line.path[1][2], line.path[1][3], line.path[1][4], 0.5);
            var p1 = makeCurvePoint(pt.x, pt.y, null, line, null)
            p1.name = "p1";
            p1.id = line_number;
            canvas.add(p1);

            var p0 = makeCurveCircle(posx, posy, line, p1, null);
            p0.name = "p0";
            p0.id = line_number;
            canvas.add(p0);

            var p2 = makeArrow(posx+100, posy+100, null, p1, line);
            p2.name = "p2";
            p2.id = line_number;
            canvas.add(p2);

            var dx = line.path[1][3] - posx;
            var dy = line.path[1][4] - posy;

            var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
            p2.setAngle(angle + 90);

            p2.setCoords();

            canvas.bringToFront(p2);
            canvas.bringToFront(p0);
            canvas.bringToFront(p1);

            line.p2 = p2;
        })();


        function makeArrow(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
            var c = new fabric.Triangle({
                width: 5,
                height: 5,
                left: left+5,
                top: top+5,
                strokeWidth: 10,
                fill: #000,
                opacity: 1,
                stroke: #000
            });

            c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

            c.angle = 90;

            c.line1 = line1;
            c.line2 = line2;
            c.line3 = line3;

            return c;
        }

        function makeCurveCircle(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
            var c = new fabric.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                left: left,
                top: top,
                strokeWidth: 10,
                fill: #000,
                stroke: #000
            });

            c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

            c.line1 = line1;
            c.line2 = line2;
            c.line3 = line3;

            return c;
        }

        function makeCurvePoint(left, top, line1, line2, line3) {
            var c = new fabric.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                left: left,
                top: top,
                strokeWidth: 10,
                fill: #000,
                opacity: 0,
                stroke: #000
            });

            c.hasBorders = c.hasControls = false;

            c.angle = 90;

            c.line1 = line1;
            c.line2 = line2;
            c.line3 = line3;

            return c;
        }
        var prevselobj;

        function onObjectSelected(e) {

            var activeObject = e.target;

            reinit_stroke = activeObject.stroke;

            if (activeObject.name == "p0" || activeObject.name == "p2") {

                if (prevselobj) {
                    prevselobj.line2.animate('opacity', '0', {
                        duration: 200,
                        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                    });
                    prevselobj.line2.selectable = false;
                }

                activeObject.line2.animate('opacity', '1', {
                    duration: 200,
                    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                });
                activeObject.line2.selectable = true;

                prevselobj = activeObject;

            }

        }

        function onBeforeSelectionCleared(e) {
            var activeObject = e.target;
            if (activeObject.name == "p0" || activeObject.name == "p2") {
              activeObject.line2.animate('opacity', '0', {
                duration: 200,
                onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
              });
              activeObject.line2.selectable = false;
            }
            else if (activeObject.name == "p1") {
              activeObject.animate('opacity', '0', {
                duration: 200,
                onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
              });
              activeObject.selectable = true;
            }
        }

        function onObjectMoving(e) {
            if (e.target.name == "p0" || e.target.name == "p2") {
                var p = e.target;

                var curvedline;

                if (p.line1) {
                    p.line1.path[0][1] = p.left;
                    p.line1.path[0][2] = p.top + p.height/2;
                    curvedline = p.line1;
                } else if (p.line3) {
                    p.line3.path[1][3] = p.left;

                    if(p.line3.path[0][2] <= p.line3.path[1][4])
                      p.line3.path[1][4] = p.top - p.height/2;

                    if(p.line3.path[0][2] > p.line3.path[1][4])
                      p.line3.path[1][4] = p.top + p.height/2;

                    p.line3.setCoords();

                    curvedline = p.line3;
                }

                if (curvedline) {
                    curvedline.setCoords();
                    var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(curvedline.path[0][1], curvedline.path[0][2], curvedline.path[1][1], curvedline.path[1][2], curvedline.path[1][3], curvedline.path[1][4], 0.5);
                    p.line2.left = pt.x;
                    p.line2.top = pt.y;

                    if (curvedline.p2) {
                        var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(curvedline.path[0][1], curvedline.path[0][2], curvedline.path[1][1], curvedline.path[1][2], curvedline.path[1][3], curvedline.path[1][4], 0.99);

                        curvedline.p2.left = pt.x;
                        curvedline.p2.top = pt.y;

                        var dx = curvedline.path[1][3] - pt.x;
                        var dy = curvedline.path[1][4] - pt.y;

                        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
                        curvedline.p2.setAngle(angle + 90);

                        curvedline.p2.setCoords();
                    }
                    p.line2.setCoords();
                }

                if (e.target.text) {
                    e.target.text.left = p.left;
                    e.target.text.top = p.top;
                    e.target.text.setCoords();
                }

            } else if (e.target.name == "p1") {
                var p = e.target;

                if (p.line2) {
                    p.line2.path[1][1] = p.left;
                    p.line2.path[1][2] = p.top;
                }

                curvedline = p.line2;

                if (curvedline) {
                    var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(curvedline.path[0][1], curvedline.path[0][2], curvedline.path[1][1], curvedline.path[1][2], curvedline.path[1][3], curvedline.path[1][4], 0.5);
                    p.left = pt.x;
                    p.top = pt.y;
                    p.setCoords();
                }

                if (curvedline) {
                      var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(curvedline.path[0][1], curvedline.path[0][2], curvedline.path[1][1], curvedline.path[1][2], curvedline.path[1][3], curvedline.path[1][4], 0.99);

                      curvedline.p2.left = pt.x;
                      curvedline.p2.top = pt.y;

                      var dx = curvedline.path[1][3] - pt.x;
                      var dy = curvedline.path[1][4] - pt.y;

                      var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
                      curvedline.p2.setAngle(angle + 90);

                      curvedline.p2.setCoords();
                }

            } else if (e.target.name == "p0" || e.target.name == "p2") {
                var p = e.target;

                p.line1 && p.line1.set({
                    'x2': p.left,
                    'y2': p.top
                });
                p.line2 && p.line2.set({
                    'x1': p.left,
                    'y1': p.top
                });
                p.line3 && p.line3.set({
                    'x1': p.left,
                    'y1': p.top
                });
                p.line4 && p.line4.set({
                    'x1': p.left,
                    'y1': p.top
                });
            }
            p && reinit();
        }
        function reinit() {
            canvas.remove(line);
            line = new fabric.Path(line.path, { fill: '',selectable: false });
            line.id = line_number;
            line.stroke = reinit_stroke;
            canvas.add(line);
            canvas.sendBackwards(line);
        }


        canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
            if(e.target.type == "path")
            {
                canvas.sendBackwards(e.target);
            }

          });
```

I am using following code for delete the tool.

(Note: this code runs when I click on the delete button. 
 Delete button deletes the object selected.  )

here is the code...

```
    var objs = canvas.getObjects();

    if (activeObject) {
        active_id = activeObject.get('id');

        canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
            if(obj.get('id') == active_id)
            {
                if(obj.type == 'path')
                {
                    obj.selectable = true;
                    canvas.remove(obj);
                }
                canvas.remove(obj); 
            }
        });

        canvas.remove(activeObject);    
    }
```

the issue I am getting is after delete this, If I create one other curved arrow in the designer(i.e. without reload the page) and move the nodes then its still showing the old path object which we already deleted.

and If I delete the newly created curved arrow then it removes all path from canvas, In short all Path object behave like one(Hope this is understandable) .

so, the path object is not getting deleted properly it is just getting hidden when I am deleting it. Or may be it is deleted but created again when I am moving another path object..
and if we save the canvas as json then we can see the path objects which are deleted too.

What I need to do is to delete the path object properly and save just the Path object currently showing on the canvas with nodes.

Please tell me if there is some solution for this issues..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the delete curve Issue.
We need to change the code at the reinit() functions.
It was overwrite the line_id to all the line(or say path) in the canvas.
Here is the code to replace with reinit() function..

```
       function reinit() {
            var objs = canvas.getObjects();
            current_line = canvas.getActiveObject();
            canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
                if(obj.type == 'path' && obj.get("id") == current_line.get("id"))
                {
                    canvas.remove(obj);
                    line = new fabric.Path(obj.path, { fill: '',selectable: false });
                    line.id = current_line.get("id");
                    line.stroke = reinit_stroke;
                    canvas.add(line);
                    canvas.sendBackwards(line);
                }               
            });

        }
```

Hope this can be helpful for someone who need this kind of solution..